# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'positions' was corrupted

Tags: c++, structure

Im having a problem returning a structure. It says Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'positions' was corrupted and i have no idea why. I have to finish this by tonight to proceed with the rest of the project. Do help if you know. thank you :)

```
struct Position
{
    int SrcDstScore[50][5];
    char pieceColor [50][2];
};

int Sort(Position s2, Position s1)
{
    int x; // use compreto method
    return x;
}
Position EvaluateMoves(Piece * theBoard[8][8])
{   
    //store my result boards here 
    Position positions;
    for (int t=0; t<50; t++)
    {
        positions.SrcDstScore[t][1]= 0;
        positions.SrcDstScore[t][2]= 0;
        positions.SrcDstScore[t][3]= 0;
        positions.SrcDstScore[t][4]= 0;
        positions.SrcDstScore[t][5]= 0;
        positions.pieceColor[t][1]= ' ';
        positions.pieceColor[t][2]= ' ';
        //cout << "Eval";
    }
    char mcPlayerTurn = 'w';
    int counter = 0;
    // Fetching the board containing positions of these pieces
       for (int Row = 0; Row < 8; ++Row) 
        {
            for (int Col = 0; Col < 8; ++Col)   
            {
                if (theBoard[Row][Col] != 0)
                {
                    if (theBoard[Row][Col]->GetColor() == 'w')
                    {
                        Piece * piece =  theBoard[Row][Col];
                        for (int MoveableRow = 0; MoveableRow < 8; ++MoveableRow) // Now that we have found the knight find the legal squares. 
                        {
                            for (int MoveableCol = 0; MoveableCol < 8; ++MoveableCol)   
                            {
                                if(piece->IsLegalMove(Row, Col, MoveableRow, MoveableCol, theBoard))
                                {
                                    cout << counter << theBoard[Row][Col]->GetPiece() << " " << theBoard[Row][Col]->GetColor() <<" " <<  Row <<" " <<  Col <<" " <<  MoveableRow <<" " <<  MoveableCol << "\n";
                                    positions.SrcDstScore[counter][1]= Row;
                                    positions.SrcDstScore[counter][2]= Col;
                                    positions.SrcDstScore[counter][3]= MoveableRow;
                                    positions.SrcDstScore[counter][4]= MoveableCol; 

                                    //If the move is a capture add it's value to the score
                                    if (theBoard[MoveableRow][MoveableRow] != 0)
                                    {
                                        positions.SrcDstScore[counter][5] += theBoard[MoveableRow][MoveableRow]->GetValue();

                                        if (theBoard[Row][Row]->GetValue() < theBoard[MoveableRow][MoveableRow]->GetValue())
                                        {
                                            positions.SrcDstScore[counter][5] += theBoard[MoveableRow][MoveableRow]->GetValue() - theBoard[Row][Row]->GetValue();
                                        }
                                        //Add Score for Castling
                                    }
                                    counter ++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
       }

        return positions;
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the initial loop, you're indexing in to `SrcDstScore` and `pieceColor` using indexes 1 to 5 and 1 to 2 respectively.  These should be indexes 0 to 4 and 0 to 1.

The same applies further down, on this line and the three after it:

```
positions.SrcDstScore[counter][1]= Row;
```

And in the two instances where you have `positions.SrcDstScore[counter][5]`, that should be `...[4]`

Answer (score 0):

```
 positions.pieceColor[t][1]= ' ';
 positions.pieceColor[t][2]= ' ';
```

It should be  -

```
 positions.pieceColor[t][0]= ' ';
 positions.pieceColor[t][1]= ' ';  // Array index starts from 0 to numElements - 1.
```

And is the same case with `Position::SrcDstScore` too. Array index start from 0 to 4.

Comment: @GeeKaush - In general, when you get such kind of run-time errors indicate the variable(s) trying to access locations which it is not assigned to.

Comment: @GeeKaush - Glad I was able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `theBoard` is a 2D array or pointer to 2D array of `Piece` with dimensions as `8 * 8` (for chess board) then the function declaration should look like this:

```
Position EvaluateMoves(Piece (*theBoard)[8])  // 1st way
Position EvaluateMoves(Piece theBoard[][8])  // 2nd(a) way
Position EvaluateMoves(Piece theBoard[8][8])  // 2nd(b) way
Position EvaluateMoves(Piece (&theBoard)[8][8])  // 3rd way, preferred if theBoard is an array
```